# If this indeed a right angle triangle in this exercise or is my drawing confusing me?

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

I was reading the following exercise:

> An airplane needs to fly to a city $100$ miles away. But it flies in a
> $2º$ off the correct course. When it has flown $100$ miles how far
> will it be from the town.

For my approach I considered the solution as follows:
[image]

AB=$100\cdot \sin 2º = 3.4899$ miles off

Question:
I made the assumption here that $A$ is a right angle because $SA=SB$ and $SA$ is a straight line and $A$ and $B$ are at the same level. But I am thinking that the way I have drawn it makes me think it is a right angle.
Is my approach correct?

Comment: Hint: if two sides of a triangle are equal then what type of triangle do you have and what properties does it have?

Comment: You have an isosceles triangle with two sides being $100$ miles and angle between them being $2^\circ$. Just find the third side length.

Comment: This is a job for the Law of Cosines!  (But the Law of Sines could also be applied, since you can figure out all of the angles in this triangle...)

Comment: @Jim can you see how, using the hint I gave you above, you can conclude that the angle at $A$ cannot be a right angle?

Comment: @Mufasa: Since it is isosceles, I can create a right angled triangle by a line starting from $S$ to the middle of $AB$. Hence $AB= AK + KB$ where $K$ is the middle. Then $AK= 100\cdot sin 1º = 1.74524$ since the two triangles have split the original $2º$ angle hence we have $AB = 2\cdot 1.74524 = 3.494$ ft. Have I got it right?

Comment: @MathLover: Please check my comment above

Comment: @boojum: Please check my comment above

Comment: yes Jim, you now have the right answer. Note however that you could also have used the cosine rule here as indicated by @boojum

Comment: @Mufasa: the cosine would give me $SK$ though. How would that help?

Comment: @Jim  That will also work:  there are a few available methods.  Notice that because this is a rather "skinny" triangle, the correct result isn't all that different from the inaccurate (but _approximately_ correct) $ \ 100 \sin 2º \ \   $ (because $ \ \sin 2º \ \approx \ 2 · \sin 1º \ \ ) \ . $

Comment: Cosine rule is usually written in the form $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$. Here you are given 2 sides ($a$ and $b$) and the angle between them ($C$). Using these you can find the third side $c$

Comment: @Mufasa: This gives me a bit different result. I.e. $3.4904$ while with the sin I got $3.494$. How come?

Comment: @Jim you have a numerical error somewhere. $c=2a\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(C)}2}=2a\sin\frac C2$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your original calculation where you said $AB=2\cdot1.74524=3.494 ft$. Note that $2\cdot1.74524=3.49048$ and that the units used should be miles not feet.